# Minecraft freezes Ubuntu 18.04 after 2 to 30 minutes

Tags: java, minecraft

Every time I start minecraft, after 2 to 30 minutes my whole computer freezes. Only mouse still works, but it can't click on anything. This only happens if I actually play the game, so not when I am on the main menu. I can't provide any other information, because my keyboard won't work after the freeze and the only way out is a hard-reboot.
Please help!

Comment: Are you sure Minecraft is the problem? Have you tried with another Java program, or another version of Java?

Comment: No, I don 't have an other java program. But I have tried different java versions without better results.

Comment: Could you run it via command-line and place here the output?

Comment: How? The second it freezes the terminal won't respond, just like the rest of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem sometimes in Ubuntu 18.04.  I think I remember solving it by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> to switch to another console.  After logging in there I was able to kill the Java process (use `top`, `ps`, `kill`, etc. to achieve that).  When I switched back to the X Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> in Ubuntu 18.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd> in older versions) the problem was gone.

I guess it was related to the mouse grabbing which the window of the Java process did.